# android viewpager вылет при скролле

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

делаю слайдер картинок
на странице ViewPager,

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/item_page_image_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="visible">
```

адаптер загружает в него из drawable несколько картинок

**adapter.java**

```
int[] imageres={
        R.drawable.item_1_img,
        R.drawable.item_2_img,
        R.drawable.item_3_img,
        R.drawable.item_4_img,
        R.drawable.item_5_img
};

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_page_img_fragment, container, false);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_page_img);

    imageView.setImageResource(imageres[position]);
    container.addView(imageView);


    return imageView;
}
```

при скролле картинки приложение вылетает с ошибкой

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1509)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
at ru.sharapov.catalog05.imagePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(imagePagerAdapter.java:54)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1038)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:277)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

еще вопрос. как загружать картинки в AsyncTask с сервера? при вызове из адаптера

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_page_img);  
new ImageLoader(imageView).execute(imageurl+(objects.get(position)).imgurl);
```

ничего не происходит
ImageLoader и адаптер вынесены в отдельные файлы
[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068907/how-to-call-asynctask-from-adapter-class) и еще в нескольких других местах пишут сделать адаптер внутренним классом активити. так ли это?
как лечить обе проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая проблема, согласно ошибке, состоит в том, что вы пытаетесь добавить в контейнер вьюху, у которой уже есть родитель. Т.е. вы опечатались/ошиблись и передали `imageView` вместо `itemView`. Т.е. надо так:

```
container.addView(itemView);
//вместо container.addView(imageView);
```

Вторая проблема не требует использования `AsynkTask` и пиления велосипедов. За годы существования андроида проблема загрузки и отображения картинок была решена много раз, в т.ч. такими компаниями как лицоКнига. Используете либы. Например [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

---

P.S. Не надо несколько вопросов в отдном вопросе. На один вопрос должен приходиться только один вопрос.